# Assistance with jquery variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

today i need help with some jquery, which I really do not have much knowledge of.  In the following code, where I have "variablecommentlimitneedstogehere," how do I put the variable that I have defined as commentlimit.  I have tried many different things, but have had no success.  Thanks!

```
<input type='hidden' id='commentlimit' value='8'/>
        <script>
        $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        document.getElementById("loadingcomments").style.display = 'block';
        var commentlimit = document.getElementById('commentlimit').value;
        $('#load').load('getprofilecomments.php?username=<?php echo $profilename; ?>&commentlimit=variablcommentlimitneedstogohere');
        //alert('end of page');
        }
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#load').load('getprofilecomments.php?username=<?php echo $profilename; ?>&commentlimit=' + commentlimit);`

jQuery is based on javascript, so it's the same syntax :)

PS If you're using jQuery, you can do a lot of those things easier:

`var commentlimit = $("#commentlimit").val();`

`$("#loadingcomments").css("display", "block");`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will accept this answer as soon as it will let me!

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate your string with that variable value:

```
$('#load').load('getprofilecomments.php?username=<?php echo $profilename; ?>&commentlimit=' + commentlimit);
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your load line with the following two lines and it should work for you

```
var url = 'getprofilecomments.php?username=<?php echo $profilename; ?>&commentlimit=' + $("#commentlimit").val();
$('#load').load(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

**document.getElementById** can be substituted by jQuery's **$** function, which uses your basic css selectors
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

You can get the value of an input with the **val()** function
http://api.jquery.com/val/

You can change style attributes with the **css()** function
http://api.jquery.com/css/

You can add variables to strings using basic javascript concatenation ('string' + variable)

Your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
<input type='hidden' id='commentlimit' value='8'/>
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      $("#loadingcomments").css('display','block');
      // if you are just trying to show a hidden item then $("#loadingcomments").show() can work too
      var commentlimit = $('commentlimit').val();
      var url = '/getprofilecomments.php?username=<?php echo $profilename; ?>&commentlimit=' + commentlimit
      $('#load').load(url);
    }
  });
</script>
```